# How do I change the email address that Munin alerts are sending from?

Tags: email-server, munin, alerts

The issue I'm having here is that when I get an alert from Munin, I want it to create a ticket. When the ticket it created, it sends an email back to the email address that Munin sent from each time the ticket is updated, which is not an actual email address, so it creates a "suspended" ticket.

I'd like to get rid of the suspended tickets by changing the email address that Munin sends from, which is munin@xxxxx.localdomain to our business donotreply@xxxx.com. Does anyone have any insight into how to do this?

I'm using 'mail' as an MTA.

Comment: Do you have a `contact.email.command` definition in your config ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually got it all set up and working now. I'll post a detailed answer to this in a few hours. I don't seem to have a high enough rep to answer my own question within 8 hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I figured out the solution. I had to change my email setup in /etc/munin/munin.conf from:

```
contacts me # may be unnecessary and cause warnings
contact.me.command mail -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" myemail@gmail.com
contact.me.always_send warning critical
```

to:

```
contacts me # may be unnecessary and cause warnings
contact.me.command mailx -r donotreply@xxxx.com -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" myemail@gmail.com
contact.me.always_send warning critical
```

So, basically, just had to use "mailx" instead of "mail" and also preface the subject of the email with "-r donotreply@xxx.com"

Answer (score 0):

Old question but it came up in Google and I was just trying to do basically the same thing (change the Munin notifiation sender). I was able to do it using:

```
contacts me # may be unnecessary and cause warnings
contact.me.command mail -a "From: Munin <donotreply@xxxx.com>" -s "Munin notification ${var:host}" myemail@gmail.com
contact.me.always_send warning critical
```